# Retorno seletivo de um array no php com curl

Tags: php, libcurl

Eu tenho as informações abaixo na variável $retorno 
Mas eu gostaria de exibir somente os valores [codigo]
Eu fiz

```
$retorno=json_decode($result, true);
foreach($retorno as $registro):
  print_r ('Código: ' . $registro['codigo'] . '<br>');
 endforeach;
Mas tenho o erro: Notice:  Undefined index: supplierProductId in
```

Grato.

```
Array
(
    [cadastroUnico] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [cliente] => 12345678910
                    [estoque] => Array
                        (
                            [selecao] => P02
                            [transacao] => 20190711500001
                            [codigo] => 500001
                            [unidade] => UN
                            [serial] => 7898616380127
                            [quantidade] => 15
                            [data] => 2019-07-22
                            [minimo] => 1

                        )

                    [returnCode] => OK
                    [returnMessage] => Feito
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [cliente] => 12345678910
                    [estoque] => Array
                        (
                            [selecao] => P02
                            [transacao] => 20190711500002
                            [codigo] => 500002
                            [unidade] => UN
                            [serial] => 7898616380356
                            [quantidade] => 3
                            [data] => 2019-07-22
                            [minimo] => 1

                        )

                   [returnCode] => OK
                    [returnMessage] => Feito
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

O `codigo` está dentro de `estoque` que está dentro da array que está dentro do `cadastroUnico`. Você precisa ir "acessando" cada array.

```
foreach($retorno['cadastroUnico'] as $k => $v) {
    print_r ('Código: ' . $v[estoque]['codigo'] . '<br>');
}
```

Aparentemente isto deve funcionar.